# Derivative coupling to curvature of spacetime

Tags: general-relativity, curvature, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

In this article https://arxiv.org/abs/0911.3702v2. I have tried to derive the Energy-Momentum tensor $T^{\eta}_{00}$ for FRW spacetime from the generalized Eq(2.6) but when I am applying the Ricci tensor $R_{00}=-3(\dot{H}+H^2)$ in the equation (2.6) but I can't derive the $3\eta \dot{H}\dfrac{\dot{\phi}^2}{\phi^2}$ term just like the result in Eq(2.9) instead I always obtain this term equal $-\dfrac{3}{2}R_{00}\dfrac{\dot{\phi}^2}{\phi^2}=\dfrac{9}{2}(\dot{H}+H^2)\dfrac{\dot{\phi}^2}{\phi^2}$. I don't know where I did wrong. In other terms, I do the same with the results of the article, but only this term is not correct. Can someone help me? Thanks for reading.